# Connect to Oracle via sqoop on Hortonworks Sandbox

Tags: oracle, hadoop, driver, sqoop, hortonworks-data-platform

I am currently using Hortonworks Sandbox (downloaded on their website) and I would like to run sqoop to connect to my Oracle database and retrieve information.

The steps I have already done:

- Install sqoop -> OK
- Ping my db server -> OK
- Download Oracle driver ojdbc6.jar -> OK
- Put Oracle driver ojdbc6.jar in /usr/lib/sqoop/lib -> OK
- Run `sqoop import --connect "jdbc:oracle:thin:readonly/readonly@//unixatd:1521:P1AX" --table DUAL`
  -> OK

I receive the following message:

```
15/06/16 04:25:01 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.5.2.2.4.2-2
15/06/16 04:25:01 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.
15/06/16 04:25:01 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
15/06/16 04:25:01 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
15/06/16 04:25:01 ERROR sqoop.Sqoop: Got exception running Sqoop: java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.oracledriver
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not load db driver class: oracle.jdbc.driver.oracledriver
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.makeConnection(SqlManager.java:848)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager.getConnection(GenericJdbcManager.java:52)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:736)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.execute(SqlManager.java:759)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnInfoForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:269)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypesForRawQuery(SqlManager.java:240)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.getColumnTypes(SqlManager.java:226)
        at org.apache.sqoop.manager.ConnManager.getColumnTypes(ConnManager.java:295)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.getColumnTypes(ClassWriter.java:1773)
        at org.apache.sqoop.orm.ClassWriter.generate(ClassWriter.java:1578)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.CodeGenTool.generateORM(CodeGenTool.java:96)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:478)
        at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:601)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:143)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:179)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:218)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:227)
        at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:236)
```

And from there, I just don't know what to do next.
If you could give me information on things that I could check, that could be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if oracle driver is available at:  `SQOOP_HOME/lib`

Your answer can be found here:

https://hortonworks.com/community/forums/topic/unable-to-sqoop-data-from-hdfs-to-oracle/

https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/sqoop-user/201306.mbox/%3CCANhcbvMsjxqeUefuZUe0s-Z=J2Eo9pp2wo-mRXjfBQk60+asoQ@mail.gmail.com%3E

Comment: SQOOP_HOME/lib is different from /usr/lib/sqoop/lib ?

Comment: It should not be different.but env variable should be set properly. `SQOOP_HOME is by default set to /usr/lib/sqoop/` in hortonworks. Please corss check it once. Jar should have appropriate permission. Please see the link for more detail. http://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP1/HDP-1.3.1/bk_installing_manually_book/content/rpm-chap10-1.html